# how do you connect to mssql server using RODBC?

Tags: r, rodbc

I had an Oracle db and I used RODBC connection to connect to oracle as below:

```
library(RODBC)
new_sql<-c("select * from table")
tryCatch({
            ch=odbcConnect("odbc_con",pwd = "!passwd!")
            res<-sqlQuery(ch,new_sql)
            },error = function(e) {
            print(odbcGetErrMsg(ch))          
        })
```

The database is mirgrated to mssql, and I've created a new odbc connection to mssql server, called new_odbc_con using DATA SOURCES(ODBC), using administrator tools.

When I updated the code to this:

```
tryCatch({
            ch=odbcConnect("odbc_con",pwd = "!password!")
            res<-sqlQuery(ch,new_sql)
            },error = function(e) {
            print(odbcGetErrMsg(ch))          
        })
```

I am not able to connect to the sql server and execute the sql. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it comes up again, this is what I did to fix this problem.

1. I created a system `odbc` connection using Admin Tools (Data Sources (ODBC))
2. I have update this line to `ch=odbcConnect("odbc_con",pwd = "!password!")` to
   `ch=odbcConnect("odbc_con",uid="userid",pwd = "!password!")`

worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Also provide Linux redhat solution, that need to edit 3 of these config files below before call the dsn in R

```
$ sudo nano /etc/odbc.ini 
[salesdb]
Driver=FreeTDS
Trace=No
Server=xxx
Port=1433
Database=xxxx
TDS_Version=8.0


$ sudo nano /etc/freetds.conf
# A typical Microsoft server
[salesdb]
    host = xxxx
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
    client charset = UTF-8

$ sudo nano /etc/odbcinst.ini
# Driver from the FreeTDS package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[FreeTDS]
Description     = FreeTDS
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so # this is the linux path, you can call odbcinst -q -d to see where the other drivers were installed in the system
```

lastly, you can use tsql or isql to test the session is installed properly or this command below,

```
$ odbcinst -q -s
```